# ClassNotFoundException in dalvik.system.PathClassLoader

Tags: android

i am running one android application in which i am using `ActionBar` but from supported library for `android 2.2`

i have added two external jar file as a support libraries

1. android-support-v7-appcompact.jar
2. android-support-v13.jar

but when i run the sample in my device i getting following runtime error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample/com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.NavMainActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.NavMainActivity in loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample-1.apk]
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2703)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2797)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2132)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4914)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.NavMainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample-1.apk]
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1033)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2695)
```

here is the menifest file content

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"  />

    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        >
        <activity android:name="NavMainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

order of jar files

[image]

Comment: do you have a class named NavMainActivity?

Comment: yeah its a main and launcher activity

Comment: Try to clean your project and also, in Buildpath load the 2 libraries at last. you can change the order

Comment: have change the order but m getting same error

Comment: try the gen first then src , Once it did for me , just try that

Answer (score 0):

You should not only look at errors but also at warnings (orange text color in eclipse logcat view). Dalvik class loading are often preceded by some interesting informations about why a class can't be loaded by the Dalvik, something like a super class not existing.

Comment: there is no warnings related to this application in eclipse

Comment: in the logcat ? Are you sure you removed all logcat filters ?

Comment: yeah in logcat there is one which says `12-08 13:59:49.169: W/dalvikvm(12518): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/android/navigationdrawerexample/NavMainActivity; (18)` and  superclass is `ActionBarActivity`

Comment: You got it. Why is ActionBarActivity not in your apk ?

Comment: its from `android-support-v7-appcompact.jar` which i have added in my build path

Comment: Have a look at the dex file generated by the app's build. Dexdump it : dexdump | grep -i descriptor | grep ActionBarActivity. Dexdump is inside android sdk tools. It will not be there. It is your job to find out why. Did you clean everything and rebuild ? Tried to close the project, re-open and rebuild ?

Comment: I cleaned , reopened it and re run it but same effect , i run `./dexdump | grep -i descriptor | grep ActionBarActivity` command but its saying `no file specified`